# Why do I get a runtime error 424 when trying to set a word doc from an excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

The code below so far is trying to check to determine if the word doc in a folder has certain text in the first 5 letters on the doc. When I try and set the word doc, I get a run time error most of the time. Any idea what I need to look into to find to source of the error?

````
Sub ConfereBudget()


Dim FSO As Object
Dim myFile As Object
Dim docConfer As Worksheet
Dim RngSCCA As Range
Dim RngSCCJTC As Range
Dim RngNABJC As Range
Dim RngOther As Range
Dim RngSCPPA As Range
Dim myFolder As Object
Dim docVic As Worksheet
Dim appWord As Object
Dim LastSave As Date
Dim introw As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng1088 As Range
Dim doc1088 As Object
Dim str1088 As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Set docVic = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set myFolder = FSO.getfolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)
'Set docConfer = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set docConfer = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application.16")
Set RngSCCA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SCCA-WTFC20").Range("A2:L2")
Set RngSCCJTC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SCCJTC 55").Range("A2:L2")
Set RngNABJC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NABCJ 30").Range("A2:L2")
Set RngOther = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Other Trainings").Range("A2:L2")
Set RngSCPPA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SCPPA 40").Range("A2:L2")

appWord.Visible = False

For Each myFile In myFolder.Files
    LastSave = FileDateTime(myFile)
    If Right(myFile, 5) = ".docx" Then
        introw = docConfer.Cells(docConfer.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        i = 3
        'trying to determine if the word doc is a 1088 by looking at the first 5 characters of the document
        'unable to set the word doc
        str1088 = myFile
        Set doc1088 = appWord.documents.Open(str1088) ****Error here***

        Set rng1088 = doc1088.Range(Start:=0, End:=5)
        MsgBox (rng1088.Text)
    End If

Next



End Sub```
````

Comment: Instead `CreateObject("Word.Application.16")` try `CreateObject("Word.Application")`

Comment: Does `str1088 = myFile` returns the full path of the file? Not sure if the active working folder for appWord is the same as ThisWorkbook.Path.

Comment: Is that the full code? Nothing left out that might be closing the Word app?

Comment: @Teamothy, I get the same error when I use "Word.Application".

Comment: @VincentG, Yes, the full path of the file is returned.

Comment: @Rory This is where I am at so far. The end goal is to extract certain parts of the doc to an excel doc, but I'm stuck at this error. Some times, I can get to the next line but that's another error I don't get to dependably and can't remember what that is right now.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was the doc I was trying to open was already open. I wasn't closing it after I tested. Now I'm embarrassed.